# WPDP related functions look to work but they don't

Tags: wpdb

I have a custom database table called **wp_wcpl_user_packages** which has the following columns:

```
id | user_id | product_id | ..irrelevant columns... | package_limit | package_timestamp | package_dduration
```

an example row would be:

```
1 | 1 | 44 | .... | 3 | 2015-09-08 22:18:44 | 90
```

What I need is a cron job to run every hour and set the `package_limit` to **-1** if the difference in days between **NOW** and the **package_timestamp** is >= of the **package_dduration**.

So I have the following two functions:

```
function get_wp_cron_get_expired_packages() {
    global $wpdb;
    $packages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wcpl_user_packages");
    $expired = array();

    foreach ($packages as $key => $package) {
        $retArray = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wcpl_user_packages
                WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), 'package_timestamp') >= 'package_dduration'
                  AND id = {$package->id}
                  AND 'package_limit' <> '-1'");
        if($retArray != null) {
            array_push($expired, $retArray);
        }
    }

    return $expired;
}
```

and

```
function wp_cron_jobs_docleanup() {
    global $wpdb;
    wp_cron_jobs_logMessages('wp cron job started at '. current_time('timestamp'));
    $packages = get_wp_cron_get_expired_packages();
    wp_cron_jobs_logMessages('Found '.count($packages).' to expire.');

    if(!empty($packages)) {
        foreach ($packages as $key => $package) {
            $wpdb->update("{$wpdb->prefix}wcpl_user_packages",
                    array(
                        'package_limit' => '-1',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'user_id' => $package->user_id,
                        'id'      => $package->id,
                    ),
                    array( '%d' ),
                    array( '%d', '%d' )
            );
            wp_cron_jobs_logMessages($package);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        wp_cron_jobs_logMessages('No Packages found to mark as expired, Exiting!');
    }   
}
```

The log always says that it didn't find any packages to expire. So, the cron runs fine but something in one of the above functions is probably wrong.

I think that it definitely is in the function that checks if there is any package that has to be expired. I have tried all kinds of different ways to write the WHERE part but never got any luck.

Please, if anyone has even the slightest hint, it would be remarkably helpful for me. Also, if you consider it is a PHP question, instead of closing this just provide me with a hint or something.

Comment: It may be a dumb point, but your example data isn't nearly old enough to expire, `DATEDIFF()` returns the number of days, so your function is looking for anything that is 90+ days old. Is that what you meant? Just pointing out that your example wouldn't satisfy your condition, in case you overlooked that. Tangentially, this could all be done with a single `UPDATE` O(1) rather than the O(N) calls you're doing now.

Comment: I have manually changed a couple of entries to be much older than this so the plugin could work but nah..   Can you explain a little bit more regarding the single UPDATE O(1) you mention? I googled it but didn't find anything

Comment: depending on the quotes you're using the `WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), 'package_timestamp') >= 'package_dduration'` may be a problem. You may need to remove the quotes, or use backticks.

Have you tried running your expired package SQL manually on the server to see if it returns what you expect?

Comment: `UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}wcpl_user_packages SET package_limit = -1 WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW(), package_timestamp) >= package_dduration AND package_limit <> -1` would effectively do the same thing, but you wouldn't get the same level of logging for each changed entry.

Comment: let me try your 3 options and I'll update you shortly. Thanks a lot for the assistance! Should I use backpacks only in the DATETIFF part?

Comment: You aren't using any special characters for your column names, so you don't really need the backticks at all. Any column reference that you want to use as the value of the column rather than the absolute string should use backticks, not quotes.

`'package_dduration' = "package_dduration"` the actual string, whereas ``.`package_timestamp` = 90``, using single quotes is a string literal, backticks or no quotes is an interpolated value.

Comment: Ignore the `.` in that backticked example, I can't figure out how to do literal backticks without it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formalizing comment answer here:

Based on the code you provided the problem is possibly that you are using literal strings rather than interpolated values in your SQL. There's a big difference between backticks `` ` `` and single-quotes `'`.

try this:

```
$retArray = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wcpl_user_packages
    WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), package_timestamp) >= package_dduration
      AND id = {$package->id}
      AND package_limit <> -1");
```

or this

```
$retArray = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wcpl_user_packages
    WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), `package_timestamp`) >= `package_dduration`
      AND `id` = {$package->id}
      AND `package_limit` <> -1");
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem - backticks. Thanks a ton for the help. I just copied your second option and voila - worked.